# How to display a message only after the third unsuccessful attempt in a function?

Tags: r, functional-programming

The following code contains the entry of a password using functional programming.

```
pw = 9999

for (i in 1:3){
pw_entered=as.numeric(readline("Please enter the password: "))

if (pw_entered==pw){
    print("The door is opened. Welcome!")
    break
    
} else {
    print("Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: ")
    
}
print("You have exceeded the maximum limit of three times. Try Later")
}
```

The output is ,

```
Please enter the password: 1
[1] "Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: "
[1] "You have exceeded the maximum limit of three times. Try Later"
Please enter the password: 2
[1] "Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: "
[1] "You have exceeded the maximum limit of three times. Try Later"
Please enter the password: 3
[1] "Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: "
[1] "You have exceeded the maximum limit of three times. Try Later"
```

I want the message `You have exceeded the maximum limit of three times. Try Later` to be displayed only after the third unsuccessful attempt and not after the first and second unsuccessful attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a `while` loop instead because it is not guaranteed that you'll have to run this 3 times every-time (If password is entered correct in the first attempt).

```
pw <- 9999
attempt <- 0
#Something which is not pw
pw_entered <- 0

while(pw_entered != pw && attempt < 3) {
   pw_entered = as.numeric(readline("Please enter the password: "))
   if (pw_entered==pw){
      print("The door is opened. Welcome!")
      break
   } 
   attempt <- attempt + 1
  if(attempt == 3)  {
     print("You have exceeded the maximum limit of three times. Try Later")
     break
  }
  else print("Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: ")
} 

#Round 1 - 
Please enter the password: 123
#[1] "Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: "
Please enter the password: 9999
#[1] "The door is opened. Welcome!"

#Round 2 - 
Please enter the password: 1234
#[1] "Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: "
Please enter the password: 21
#[1] "Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: "
Please enter the password: 23
#[1] "You have exceeded the maximum limit of three times. Try Later"
```

Comment: the break will stop the for loop as soon as correct password is given

Comment: Isn't that what is expected? Or you intend to continue attempting even after correct password is entered?

Comment: I mean that for loop will have the same behaviour as while because it will stop after the break